# How to render reusable component one at a time in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I reuse the Chat component twice into another component. It display when you click Chat button but it overlaps each other.

```
class Chat extends React.Component {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
                show: false, 
            };
        }
        reset = () => {
            this.setState(false);
        }
        open = () => { 
            this.setState({ show: true });
        }
        close = () => this.setState({ show: false });
        render() {
            return (<div className="chat">
                <button className="btn-yes round" onClick={this.open}>{this.props.title}</button>
                {this.state.show  && 
                <div className="show-chat">
                    <div className="chat-head">Now Chatting <i className="fas fa-angle-down" onClick={this.close}></i></div>
                    <div className="chat-body">
                        <div className="blue">Teresa wants to chat about her healthcare finances</div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><img src={agentPhoto} alt="chat agent avatar" /></li>
                            <li>
                                <h6>John Newman</h6>
                                <div className="gray">Hi Teresa!</div>
                                <div className="gray">Here is the <a href="/">link to the finance tool</a> we discussed.</div>
                                <div className="gray">If you have any questions, let me know!</div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <input placeholder="Type here and hit enter to chat"></input>
                </div>}
            </div>);
        }
    }
```

I expect to display chat one at a time. When I click the Chat button 2 and the Chat 1 is displayed, Chat 1 should be hidden.

Comment: Well you need to move some logic in the higher component.

Comment: What does the parent component look like?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo I dont have parent component.

Comment: I mean, the component that is using `Chat` twice.

Comment: I just include it into other component like this, <Chat title={'Show Chat'}></Chat>

Comment: @akselrows try my solution below. Let me know if that helps you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you need to give each `Chat` component an identifier and keep track of the one that is currently opened.

Here is the basic structure for your **Parent** component:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    currentChatId: null
  };

  handleOpen = id => {
    this.setState({
      currentChatId: id
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Chat
          identifier={1}
          currentChatId={this.state.currentChatId}
          handleOpen={this.handleOpen}
        />
        <Chat
          identifier={2}
          currentChatId={this.state.currentChatId}
          handleOpen={this.handleOpen}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So notice, we give each `Chat` component an `identifier` prop. We will use `identifier` to update the active chat - which we stored as a value called `currentChatId` in our parent-state. That is all done through the `handleOpen()` event-handler, which we also pass down as a prop to `Chat`.

Now in your `Chat` component, we need to configure logic for `open()` and `componentDidUpdate()`

```
class Chat extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      show: false
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { identifier, currentChatId } = this.props;

    if (this.props.currentChatId !== prevProps.currentChatId) {
      this.setState({
        show: identifier === currentChatId ? true : false
      });
    }
  }

  open = () => {
    const { identifier, handleOpen } = this.props;
    handleOpen(identifier);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="chat">
        <button className="btn-yes round" onClick={this.open}>
          {this.props.title}
        </button>
        {this.state.show && (
          <div className="show-chat">
            <div className="chat-head">
              Now Chatting{" "}
              <i className="fas fa-angle-down" onClick={this.close} />
            </div>
            <div className="chat-body">
              <div className="blue">
                Teresa wants to chat about her healthcare finances
              </div>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <img src={""} alt="chat agent avatar" />
                </li>
                <li>
                  <h6>John Newman</h6>
                  <div className="gray">Hi Teresa!</div>
                  <div className="gray">
                    Here is the <a href="/">link to the finance tool</a> we
                    discussed.
                  </div>
                  <div className="gray">
                    If you have any questions, let me know!
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <input placeholder="Type here and hit enter to chat" />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Workflow:**

1. User clicks one of the Chat buttons, triggering `handleOpen()`and we
   pass in the unique `identifier`....
2. That gets passed back up to the `Parent`, and now `currentChatId`
   should be updated with the `identifier`...
3. That `currentChatId` gets passed back down to the Chat component as the
   `currentChatId` prop...
4. Triggers `componentDidUpdate()` on all Chat components, and we check
   the `currentChatId` against their own identifiers, only one will be
   matching, so we display that one.

See codesandbox for working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-kgm2h